# Input Tensor into tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am following tutorial on [simple audio recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) and currently editing the [label_wav.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/label_wav.py).  In original case we input wave file and the graph predicts the label (in between it calculates spectrum, mfcc's inside the graph). Now i am looking to input mfcc's directly rather than inputting the wave file. [Run the graph](https://github.com/BhanuKiranChaluvadi/tensorflow_exericse/blob/master/speech_recognition_test_nn.png) by inputting the mfcc tensor.

```
# mfccs:  Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(1, 98, 40), dtype=float32)
mfcc_input_layer_name = 'Reshape:0'
with tf.Session() as sess:
    predictions, = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {mfcc_input_layer_name: mfcc})
```

After a bit of googling, i found [some discussion in git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3389) and created a [session_handle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_session_handle).

```
# mfccs:  Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(1, 98, 40), dtype=float32)
mfcc_input_layer_name = 'Reshape:0'
with tf.Session() as sess:
      h = tf.get_session_handle(mfccs)
      h = sess.run(h)
      predictions, = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {mfcc_input_layer_name: h})
```

**The code is working as expected** but I am wondering if there could be a better way of dealing with the tensor rather than creating the handle and then passing it?

Comment: Is it a known input or something that you try to force?

Comment: Know input. Which i have calculate using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/signal/mfccs_from_log_mel_spectrograms) tutorial. Except that i inputted directly the pcm.

Comment: Where does `mfcc_input_layer_name` come from? It's not in the tutorial.

Comment: Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to replace an intermediate Tensor with a value by feed_dict. If you have a Tensor object, you can replace it by feed_dict as the following

```
a = tf.constant(3, name="a")
b = tf.constant(4, name="b")
c = tf.add(a, b, name="c")
d = c * 3

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(d))    
    print(sess.run(d, feed_dict={c: 2}))
```

Even though you don't have the Tensor object, you can get it by get_tensor_by_name

```
a = tf.constant(3, name="a")
b = tf.constant(4, name="b")
c = tf.add(a, b, name="c")
d = c * 3

with tf.Session() as sess:
    c_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("c:0")
    print(sess.run(d, feed_dict={c_tensor: 2}))
```